# xamarin android starting blocking GC eXPLICIT?

Tags: android, xamarin

i have an app under visual studio 2015 and xamarin (MVVM light / sql light).
this app use a scan engine for to scan a barcode.
In my app, i have a tab who contains three fragment where user can swipe , and on each fragment user can add some product (barcode) into a recyclerView.

when i used the app sometimes i have the message : app has stopped !!!
i'm boring i'm boring about this issue and i can't find how to resolve or advance for to resolve this or find what's happens ...

if i look onto the debug into visual studio i have this

```
06-26 08:47:52.957 I/ADT     (24874): ScanService`1 : OnScan BARCODE CODE 
SCANNED: 17DD044016 Target ViewModel xxx
06-26 08:47:52.960 I/ADT     (24874): xxx : Insert IN
06-26 08:47:52.960 I/ADT     (24874): xxx : WriteSingleOperation IN
06-26 08:47:52.996 I/ADT     (24874): xxx : WriteSingleOperation OUT
06-26 08:47:52.997 I/ADT     (24874): xxx : Insert OUT
06-26 08:47:53.039 I/art     (24874): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
The thread 0x1c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
06-26 08:47:53.119 I/art     (24874): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 
13066(1132KB) AllocSpace objects, 54(1052KB) LOS objects, 9% free, 
154MB/170MB, paused 595us total 80.198ms
06-26 08:47:53.122 D/Mono    (24874): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 629 objects 1473 
opaque 792 colors 643 colors-bridged 629 colors-visible 629 xref 144 cache- 
hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 14 setup 0.15ms tarjan 1.35ms scc-setup 
0.20ms gather-xref 0.06ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.12ms
06-26 08:47:53.122 D/Mono    (24874): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 
87.25ms
06-26 08:47:53.122 D/Mono    (24874): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 9.05ms, 
stw 9.39ms promoted 172K major size: 2928K in use: 2220K los size: 1024K in 
use: 221K
invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xabe7cea0 passed to dlfree06-26 
08:47:53.136 F/libc    (24874): invalid address or address of corrupt block 
0xabe7cea0 passed to dlfree
```

any idea are welcome, what i can do for to avoid this problem ?

i have try to put more memory with => java max heap size but my problem isn't resolve ...

thanks for your time and your explanation

Comment: You can try enabling the Concurrent GC (Android Build / Code Generation and runtime) but it sounds like you need to optimize the images that are being shown in the recyclerview, they should be resized/cached to the actual size needed for the current view size.

Comment: Hello sunsihanover, thanks for your idea, i've delete my imageView inside the layout cell. this layout is the same into the three fragment. I scan barcode , click on add button, swipe, repeat ... but sometimes app has stopped !!!!! I wonder, i'm not an expert but i wonder if on each fragment when i click on button add a progressdialog ? my call is an async but perhaps if i add a progressdialog the problem can be solve ?? what do you think ?